# Using an array of random words in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Good evening.

I am trying to create a hangman game in C#. It works fine when I use just one secret word (In this example, the word HASHTAG is used).
But I need to get it to work using an array of words as per those featured in the multi-line comments.

Can anyone please offer assistance?

My full code follows...

---

```
class HangManGame
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Title = ("Hangman Game");
        string secretword = "HASHTAG";

        /*string[] secretword = {
        "MARIO", "SONIC", "THELEGENDOFZELDA", "DONKEYKONG", "LUIGI",
        "PEACH", "LINK", "LARACROFT", "BOWSER", "KRATOS",
        "PLAYSTATION", "NINTENDO", "TETRIS", "GRANDTHEFTAUTO",
        "FINALFANTASY", "THELASTOFUS", "GHOSTOFTSUSHIMA", "HORIZONZERODAWN",
        "HALO", "FORZA", "CRASHBANDICOOT", "WORLDOFWARCRAFT", "CALLOFDUTY",
        "FORTNITE", "ANIMALCROSSING", "DOOM", "METALGEARSOLID", "MINECRAFT",
        "RESIDENTEVIL", "PACMAN", "SPACEINVADERS", "ASTEROIDS",
        "STREETFIGHTER", "MORTALKOMBAT", "SUPERMARIOKART", "POKEMON",
        "BIOSHOCK", "TOMBRAIDER"
        }; */


        List<string> letterGuessed = new List<string>();
        int live = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome To Hangman!");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a letter to guess for a {0} Letter Word ", secretword.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("You Have {0} Lives remaining \n", live);
        Isletter(secretword, letterGuessed);
        while (live > 0)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (letterGuessed.Contains(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Entered Letter [{0}] already", input);
                Console.WriteLine("Try a Different Letter \n");
                GetAlphabet(input);
                continue;
            }
            letterGuessed.Add(input);
            if (IsWord(secretword, letterGuessed))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine(secretword);
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations!");
                break;
            }
            else if (secretword.Contains(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good Entry \n");
                string letters = Isletter(secretword, letterGuessed);
                Console.Write(letters);
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That Letter Is Not In My Word");
                live -= 1;
                Console.WriteLine("You Have {0} Lives Remaining", live);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (live == 0)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Game Over \nMy Secret Word is [ {0} ]", secretword);
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static bool IsWord(string secretword, List<string> letterGuessed)
    {
        bool word = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < secretword.Length; i++)
        {
            string c = Convert.ToString(secretword[i]);
            if (letterGuessed.Contains(c))
            {
                word = true;
            }
            else
            {
                return word = false;
            }
        }
        return word;
    }
    static string Isletter(string secretword, List<string> letterGuessed)
    {
        string correctletters = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < secretword.Length; i++)
        {
            string c = Convert.ToString(secretword[i]);
            if (letterGuessed.Contains(c))
            {
                correctletters += c;
            }
            else
            {
                correctletters += "_ ";
            }
        }
        return correctletters;
    }
    static void GetAlphabet(string letters)
    {
        List<string> alphabet = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 26; i++)
        {
            char alpha = Convert.ToChar(i + 96);
            alphabet.Add(Convert.ToString(alpha));
        }
        int num = 49;
        Console.WriteLine("Letters Left are :");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            if (letters.Contains(letters))
            {
                alphabet.Remove(letters);
                num -= 1;
            }
            Console.Write("[" + alphabet[i] + "] ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Use the Random class to generate a random number between 0 and one less than the length of the secretword array. Use that number as an index to select a word from the array.

Comment: Are you need select one random word from an array?

Comment: Fyi `string input = Console.ReadLine();` is probably not the right method here as the user can enter any string of characters they'd like. For instance they could enter `Hash` instead of `H`. It also looks to be case-sensitive when checking input against secret. Might not be ideal.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the issue with case sensitivity. As you can probably gather, I'm a bit of a coding noob with C# (more used to Java) ... Any suggestion on a fix for case sensitivity?

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of 'Honeyboy Wilson' comment

```
 Random random = new Random();
 string secretword = secretwords[random.Next(0, secretwords.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the declaration order and use the `Random` class to pick a value from the Array?

```
string[] secretWords = {
    "MARIO", "SONIC", "THELEGENDOFZELDA", "DONKEYKONG", "LUIGI",
    "PEACH", "LINK", "LARACROFT", "BOWSER", "KRATOS",
    "PLAYSTATION", "NINTENDO", "TETRIS", "GRANDTHEFTAUTO",
    "FINALFANTASY", "THELASTOFUS", "GHOSTOFTSUSHIMA", "HORIZONZERODAWN",
    "HALO", "FORZA", "CRASHBANDICOOT", "WORLDOFWARCRAFT", "CALLOFDUTY",
    "FORTNITE", "ANIMALCROSSING", "DOOM", "METALGEARSOLID", "MINECRAFT",
    "RESIDENTEVIL", "PACMAN", "SPACEINVADERS", "ASTEROIDS",
    "STREETFIGHTER", "MORTALKOMBAT", "SUPERMARIOKART", "POKEMON",
    "BIOSHOCK", "TOMBRAIDER"
};

Random R = new Random();
string secretword = secretWords[R.Next(secretWords.Length)];
```